# ETL in oracle using straight sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, etl

could somebody explain me how to load data from one oracle db to another db or with in the same db to load tables under a different schema using straight sql in an efficient manner. This is plain ETL work and I have never worked with ETL scripts before. Appreciate your help

Best Regards..

Comment: What kind of ETL tool do you want to use? There are quite a number of them one of the intriguing one is the one that uses a Java RFX engine and mix of XML and Shell scripts.

Comment: ETL tools are not always the answer. Plain SQL, in PL/SQL wrappers and DBMS_Scheduler as the control mechanism is faster and more reliable than an ETL tool when it's done right.

Comment: @Annjawn although I'm familiar with ODI and know how to use it, I want to use straight SQL for this task.

Comment: @David  Thank you for the reply. Could you please provide me any useful links which would help me in achieving this task.

Comment: @user1751356 have a good read of the Oracle documentation for your current version, in particular the data warehousing guide. It describes all of the optimisations and techniques you'd need. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/toc.htm or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/toc.htm for example

Comment: I will go through them...thank you for sharing the information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can establish a [dblink](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) then its simple - just INSERT INTO....SELECT...

If you don't have a dblink then it's not possible just using SQL - since SQL only runs within a database session. Hence you'll need some sort of scripting to start a session on the source database run queries on it then start a session on the target database and run queries there. As to what is the best way of doing that....well there's far too many choices to give a sensible answer - especially when we don't even know what OS you're using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would agree that I need some sort of scripting in order to be able to schedule the work .I have no experience in writing scripts. Could you provide me some useful links which would help me get started and the OS I believe is RHEL. Again, thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Data pump is a good option for moving bulk data from one database to another, as is tablespace transport. SQL across a dblink is constrained to run serially on the link itself so if you need high performance you need multiple session running the insert/select